# Add a serial number to each unique Print page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, printing, label

I have PDF labels that I print that are identical. So for example I might have a document named "PDF123" and then I generate it to print 5 times. I want to have 5 unique numbers inserted as an overlay in each individual label so I can tell them apart.

I was thinking I could do this with a chrome extension, or maybe with some kind of script. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is we are actually using this in a warehouse environment. So for example we have a page called 123. And when the system says how many do you want to print and I print 5 They are all identical. I need a way to insert a barcode that I can scan that is unique for each one. The good news is the QTY of 5 is rendered server side not on the print spool, and I have script/html access. I just need to figure out how to do that.